# multi language website automatically by their country (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, ip, multilingual

I'm trying to develop a multi language website with asp.net MVC which it should automatically recognize country of clients and then show the web site with their language.
I can get IP Address but I cant find their country. I used a web service 
here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using global_vrf.GeoIpService;

namespace global_vrf.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        string userIpAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
        ViewBag.userIpAddress = userIpAddress;



        GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();
        GeoIP output = service.GetGeoIP(userIpAddress);
        ViewBag.usercountry = output;
        return View();
    }


 }
}
```

and I have written this in my view to check whats happen

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

}
@Resources.Home_txt.AppDes

<br />

@ViewBag.userIpAddress
<br />
@ViewBag.usercountry
```

and this is the output:

```
93.110.112.199 
global_vrf.GeoIpService.GeoIP  //this line is showing instead of country name.
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@ViewBag.userCountry` is outputting `global_vrf.GeoIpService.GeoIP`, then that means that's the *type* of the thing you're putting into that `ViewBag` member and that type has no customized `ToString` overload. When presented with any given type to render, Razor will simply call `ToString` on it, to get something to actually output. The default for `ToString` is return the type name and namespace.

More likely, you'd want to do something like:

```
@{ var userCountry = ViewBag.userCountry as global_vrf.GeoIpService.GeoIP; }
@if (userCountry != null)
{
    @userCountry.Country;
}
```

Where `Country` would be the property on `global_vrf.GeoIpService.GeoIP` that actually holds the country name you're looking to actually see output.

Comment: thanks for your care, when i put your codes on my index page this line has error `@userCountry.Country;` processing your request. what should I do next?

Comment: Well, first, `Country` is just what I made up. If the property you're after isn't actually called `Country`, you need to use *that* name instead. Second, what error are you getting? It's pretty much impossible to help you solve an error if I don't know what that error is.

Comment: thanks again for your care, this is the Error `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'global_vrf.GeoIpService.GeoIP' does not contain a definition for 'Country' and no extension method 'Country' accepting a first argument of type 'global_vrf.GeoIpService.GeoIP' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Okay, then, like I said, the class doesn't actually have that property. `Country` was just a placeholder. Change the property name to whatever *does* hold the value you want on that class.

Comment: I'm not sure what to change to. but really thank you for your time and help

Comment: Debug and look at what the return from the service call is. Inspect the object and find the member that has the information you want.

Comment: wooow it works fine with this `@userCountry.CountryName` really thank you. helped alot. thank you 1000...000 times

Answer (score 1):

please use geoipresult and then fetch the countryname

```
  <GetGeoIPResult>

    <CountryName>string</CountryName>
    <CountryCode>string</CountryCode>
  </GetGeoIPResult>
```

Comment: thank you for your care, but no matter, you meant I should do this? `<GetGeoIPResult>
    <CountryName>@ViewBag.usercountry</CountryName>
    <CountryCode>string</CountryCode>
 </GetGeoIPResult>`no difference in result